# back to back or gates with object comparisons. Confusion

Tags: javascript

To put it simply, i do not understand why they second if statement did not return false for the example (null, null)

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object")
    return false;

  var propsInA = 0, propsInB = 0;

  for (var prop in a)
    propsInA += 1;

  for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1;
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
      return false;
  }

  return propsInA == propsInB;
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

Comment: Both your a and b are null right ?

Comment: coz `a===b` for `null, null`, first if return

Answer (score 0):

Comes from the definition of `===`.

As referenced in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) this actually boils down to the [definition from Ecma](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) for `===`, where it is stated for `x === y`:

> ...
>   1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
>
> ...
>   3. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
>
> ...

If you call your function with `(null, null)`, then:

1. Type(x) and Type(y) are the same
2. Type(x) is Null

   ∴ `null === null` ⇒ `true`

Comment: Right, because of the first point in the enumeration, I'll add that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using an [ECMA](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) with a `null` value will always return `true`.

So - your function will **never** return `false` when you pass it a `null` value - beacuse it will always meet the first `if` condition , `a === b`, and `return true;`. The `return` statement stops its execution, and will never reach the 2nd `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

If your code execute return, the next code will not being executed..

Answer (score 0):

Swap your if statements. because return will exit the function and null=== null so it will execute the first loop and will not go to the next loop

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {

   if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
       b == null || typeof b != "object") {
       return false;
   }
    if (a === b) {
    return true;
   }

 }
var c = null;
 console.log(deepEqual(c, c));
```

Comment: i got this from https://github.com/marijnh/Eloquent-JavaScript/blob/master/code/solutions/04_4_deep_comparison.js

and when i tested there code it worked for all 3 examples :(

console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true

Comment: This code is perfectly right, if you want to check the equality of two objects.
This code is available in some of libraries to check the equality of two object.

Comment: i get it now.  What i was not understanding is that the first line a ===b was only returning true for the first test because the same pointer "obj" is used, but the 3rd example shows that this is bypassed and the recursive loop is needed

Comment: The whole purpose of building this script is to handle 3rd condition.
Both a and b are same but located in different memory location. In this scenario we need to compare element by element.
Of u don't have third requirement , simply equal will work

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning .before the second statement execute

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) {
    //return true;
  }

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
    b == null || typeof b != "object") {
    return false;
  }
}
var c = null;
console.log(deepEqual(c, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because first statement is true and it return from here. After return next line code is not executed.**

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) {
    //return true;
  }

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
    b == null || typeof b != "object") {
    return false;
  }
}
var c = null;
console.log(deepEqual(c, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your functions exits out at the first if statement ergo returning false.

`if (a === b) {
    return true;
  }`

It is also generally considered good practice to have a single return statement within your functions. In our case, we could refactor our code to something like this:

```js
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  var ret = false;
  if (a === b) {
    ret = true;
  } else if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
    b == null || typeof b != "object") {
    ret = false;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

This also caters for another possible problem. There are values of a and b that would not have been caught by either if statements and would have returned undefined. e.g:

deepEqual([], {});

Comment: Im following everyone's great feedback, but there is something i need to explain further about my misunderstanding.  

The purpose of this code is to make a more accurate comparison than just "===", but it seems that "===" is able to determine that for the second example given (see bottom of code), that a and be are not equal (as it doesn't return true in the fist chunk of code).  So if  "===" can do this for objects, why do we even need to loop through them with the "prop in a" lines?